# Which word is this use of かめ specifying?

Tags: translation, homophonic-kanji

In Kenji Miyazawa's poem "Thief", many words are left as hiragana:

> 青じろい骸骨星座のよあけがた
>
> 凍えた泥の乱反射をわたり
>
> 店さきにひとつ置かれた
>
> 提婆のかめをぬすんだもの
>
> にはかにもその長く黒い脚をやめ
>
> 二つの耳に二つの手をあて
>
> 電線のオルゴールを聴く

What does 提婆のかめ signify? (I tried doing a few searches, but I can't tell if this is related to a [shogi piece](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%8F%90%E5%A9%86) or an [Aryadeva figure](http://www.rigpawiki.org/index.php?title=Aryadeva)). According to [this site](http://reservata.s123.coreserver.jp/poem-kenzi/syura1-7.htm), it refers to Datta Daiba, but that doesn't clear up the mystery with かめ.

Comment: 「瓶」= pot, jar.  Could not think of another possibility.

Comment: Does the Aryadeva normally have a pot?

Comment: I could only say "sometimes" if you image-search, including the drawing you linked to.

Comment: what is it for?

Comment: No knowledge of it.  For holding water would be my best guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I located another version of the poem as follows:

ぬすびと

青じろい骸骨星座のよあけがた

凍えた泥の乱(らん)反射をわたり

店さきにひとつ置かれた

青磁のかめをぬすんだもの

にはかにもその長く黒い脚をやめ

二つの耳に二つの手をあて

電線のオルゴールを聴く

Here 青磁のかめ = celadon pot.
Thus 提婆のかめ may mean "the pot isolated like Aryadeva."

Anyway, the poem is enigmatic with plenty of room for speculation including this -> http://kdiary1.fc2.com/cgi-bin/d.cgi/giton/?dt=20121006.